# Prevent disappearing of a Layout after a while

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have two Layouts. When I want to close `Layout B` ,`Layout A` should appear.Everything works fine till now.

But when I let my app running in the background for a while and try to get from `Layout B` to `A` again , Layout A is not appearing and it shows me the Android start menu. Im closing my `Layout B` with the normal method `finish();` if this helps.

How can I prevent this ? Is Android trying to recycle my `Layout A` after a while ?

**EDIT**:

Scenario:

```
1. Starting App -> `Layout A` appears

2. From Layout A I start `Layout B` (with a Button normal startActivity function with an Intent)

3. Layout B is visible. Now I dont use my App for a while

4. After a while I open my device and see my Layout B which I started the last.When I click my Back button my App is returning back to android home menu. No Layout is visible (It should be Layout A visible)
```

Manifest:

**Layout A(with Application part) :**

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Layout B:**

```
<activity
        android:name="Full"
        android:label="GGWP"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Android start menu" ? Does that mean your app closes after calling `finish()` in activity with layout B?

Comment: Exactly.But its not really closed its running in background but you have to click it again from the process list. But for the user it looks like the app is being closed. Could I explain it ? So the previous layout is not being displayed it just kicks you to android home menu

Comment: can you put your part of code here..

Comment: I edited my first post hopefully its better understandble. Which code do u need specific ?

Comment: It's very possible your layout could be recycled, but for completeness, show the manifest and the code used to start Activity A and B

Comment: I updated my first post with the Layout code of my manifest and a first part of my <Application> tag